# IOS app Nav bar back button

Tags: ios, iphone, button, navigation

I have looked at all the navigation bars on all the story board scenes of my app, and I have gone through all the view controller m. files and there is no mention anywhere of the navigation bars settings. The mystery is that I have two different pages, one where the back button is in lower case (back), another where it is in title case (Back), and other pages just have the cursor image < or nothing at all. If I click on the storyboard navigation bar area, it highlights in blue, and there nothing obviously there.

I cannot find where this has been defined !!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard check the previous view controller settings (the Controller before Controller with back button).

1. Select View Controller
2. Select Navigation Item
3. Select Attributes inspector tab (triangle icon)
4. Check Back Button field **(there could be invisible symbols like spaces)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you - knowing this and just writing in my own "Back" everywhere has solved it!